# jQuery event binding with accessibility in mind - click and keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just a quick question, I seem to do this a lot:

```
$saveBtn.bind("click keypress", function(e)
{
    if (e.type != "keypress" || e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        // Do something...

        return false;
    }
});
```

Is there a quicker way to bind an 'action' listener to a button? I want to always ensure my buttons with event listeners fire on both clicks and the enter key...this seems like it'd be a fairly common thing to want to do but found nothing on google. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By binding it with `click` will do the job, no need for keep press. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NSpb3/)

Comment: This actually only works for elements with native keyboard support, like A tags and Button tags and whatnot - this will not, for instance, work for a div tag.

Comment: jedd.ahyoung is correct... if you want to bind an element like <span> to respond to a click.. and/or for A11y to respond to a keypress... you must define both... for example `jQuery('.element').on('click keypress', function () {// do something} );`

Answer (score 5):

The click event doesn't actually handle the keypress in every case, it's the button that is making the click event work. When you use a div with a tabindex attribute to make it keyboard accessible, the click handler will not trigger when you press enter.

HTML

```
<div id="click-only" tabindex="0">Submit click only</div>
<div id="click-and-press" tabindex="0">Submit click and press</div>​
```

jQuery

```
$("#click-only").click(function (e) {
    addToBody(); // Only works on click
});

$("#click-and-press").bind("click keypress", handleClickAndPress(function (e) {
    addToBody(); // Works on click and keypress
}));

function addToBody() {
    $("body").append($("<p/>").text("Submitted"));
}

function handleClickAndPress(myfunc) {
    return function (e) {
        if (e.type != "keypress" || e.keyCode == 13) {
            myfunc(e);
        }
    };
}
```

So to answer the question, I don't think there is a better way (that works in every case) other than yoda2k's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a second function which handles the additional logic and pass your function as a parameter:

```
function handleClickAndPress(myfunc)
{
    return function (e) {
        if (e.type != "keypress" || e.keyCode == 13) {
            myfunc(e);
        }
    };
}

$saveBtn.bind("click keypress", handleClickAndPress(function (e) {
    // do your stuff here
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's part of a form you could just listen for the "submit" event?

Comment: Yes true and in the above example it is, although this form has multiple submit buttons, all of which behave slightly differently (if the user has JS enabled). But I'm still looking for a more general solution.